# Get a problem when make a hangman game ? ( c language)

Tags: c, function, if-statement, error-messaging

I'm still really new to the C language and I'm trying to make a hangman game but I keep failing to end the game when I win.

Here is the code:

```
const int true = 1;
const int false = 0;

char words[][20] = {
    "hangman",
    "computer",
    "programming",
    "microsoft",
    "visual",
    "studio",
    "express",
    "learning"
};
    
int isletterinword(char word[], char letter)
{
    int i;    
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
        if (word[i] == letter) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
    
int iswordcomplete(char secretword[], char rights[])
{
    int i;    
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(secretword); i++) {            
        if (rights[i] == secretword[i] ) {                
            return true;                
        }
    }    
    return false;
}
    
void printhangman(int numofwrongs)
{
    // Line 1
    printf("\t  ______\n");

    // Line 2
    printf("\t  |     |\n");

    // Line 3
    printf("\t  |     +\n");

    // Line 4 - left arm, head and right arm
    printf("\t  |");
    if (numofwrongs > 0) printf("    \\");
    if (numofwrongs > 1) printf("O");
    if (numofwrongs > 2) printf("/");
    printf("\n");

    // Line 5 - body
    printf("\t  |");
    if (numofwrongs > 3) printf("     |");
    printf("\n");

    // Line 6 - left leg and right leg
    printf("\t  |");
    if (numofwrongs > 4) printf("    /");
    if (numofwrongs > 5) printf(" \\");
    printf("\n");

    // Line 7
    printf("\t  |\n");

    // Line 8
    printf("\t__|__\n");
}

void printletters(char letters[])
{
    int i;    
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(letters); i++) {
        printf("%c ", letters[i]);
    }
}
    
void printscreen(char rights[], char wrongs[], char secretword[])
{
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        printf("\n");
    
    printhangman(strlen(wrongs));
    printf("\n");

    printf("Correct guesses: ");
    printletters(rights);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Wrong guesses: ");
    printletters(wrongs);
    printf("\n\n\n");
      
    printf("\t");
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(secretword); i++) {
        if (isletterinword(rights, secretword[i])) {
            printf("%c ", secretword[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("_ ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i;        
    int secretwordindex;    
    char rights[20];    
    char wrongs[7];    
    char guess;        

    secretwordindex = 0;
   
    srand(time(0));
    secretwordindex = rand() % 8;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        rights[i] = '\0';
    }
 
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        wrongs[i] = '\0';
    }

    while (strlen(wrongs) < 6) {
        
        printscreen(rights, wrongs, words[secretwordindex]);

        printf("\nPlease enter your guess: ");
        scanf(" %c", &guess);

        if (isletterinword(words[secretwordindex],guess)) {
            
            rights[strlen(rights)] = guess;
        }

        else {
            
            wrongs[strlen(wrongs)] = guess;
        }
       
    } 

    printscreen(rights, wrongs, words[secretwordindex]);

    if ( iswordcomplete(words[secretwordindex],rights[20])==true &&  strlen(wrongs) <= 6  ) { // The if condition here might be problematic.
        printf("You have won!\n");
    }
    else { 
        printf("You have lost!\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

> main.c:197:48: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘iswordcomplete’ makes
> pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conver   sion]
> main.c:55:5: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’

Comment: `if ( iswordcomplete(words[secretwordindex],rights)...)` is enough

Comment: thx for help , it really help. But after i correct this sentence ,I still cant print out the message when I win .Is there still get other problems in my  code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: The compiler error is caused by the fact that you are passing a *single* character to your call to `iswordcomplete()`, rather than an *array* of characters. So, in the check near the end of your `main` function, you need to pass `rights` (unadorned) as the argument, in place of `rights[20]` (which, incidentally, is an out-of-bounds element of the array). Also, you don't – at that stage – need the second check (counting the number of wrongs – see later). Here's the fix for that part of the code:

```c
//  if (iswordcomplete(words[secretwordindex], rights[20]) == true && strlen(wrongs) <= 6) { // The if condition here might be problematic.
    if (iswordcomplete(words[secretwordindex], rights)){// && strlen(wrongs) <= 6) { // Needs the whole string as an argument
        printf("You have won!\n");
    }
```

Now to address a couple of other issues that will stop your code from working properly ...

**(1)** Your main `while` loop won't stop running *until* you have entered 6 'wrong' letters – even if you **do** guess the word correctly. So, you need to add an `iswordcomplete()` check to the `while` condition (negating it with the `!`operator<sup>†</sup>), to keep running the loop *only* if the word *isn't* complete. Like this:

```c
    while (strlen(wrongs) < 6 && !iswordcomplete(words[secretwordindex], rights)) { // Need to break loop if we win!!

        printscreen(rights, wrongs, words[secretwordindex]);
        //...
```

**(2)** The logic of your `iswordcomplete` function is flawed, as it will return "true" as soon as it finds *any* match. Instead, you need two loops, returning false if any of the word's letters ***is not found*** in the list of 'rights'. Here's one possible version:

```c
int iswordcomplete(char secretword[], char rights[])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(secretword); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(rights); j++) {
            if (secretword[i] == rights[j]) break;
        }
        if (j >= strlen(rights)) return false; // Didn't find this letter
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please feel free for any further clarification and/or explanation.

---

<sup>†</sup> If you're not (yet) familiar with this use of the `!` operator, then you can explicitly compare the function's return value to the `false` constant, if you are more comfortable with that, like so:

```c
while (strlen(wrongs) < 6 && iswordcomplete(words[secretwordindex], rights) == false) { // Break loop if we win!
```

Comment: thx for your help^^ I learn a lot from your answer^^ . But I still got a problem , when I use online c program runner , it can run normally . But when I run it in visual studio  , I get some garble codes . How can I solve this  problem?

Comment: @newer Do you mean lots of warnings about mixing signed and unsigned integers? If that's all, then change your `int` variables to `unsigned int`. (I think you can do it for *all* of them, but I wouldn't like to swear by that.) Alternatively (less good), you can cast the return values of the `strlen` function to `int`, like this: `for (i = 0; i < (int)strlen(secretword); i++) {...`

Comment: thx  , it solve the problem   ^^ .  But I still got a question , should I always use unsigned integers?